# request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method error in bots

Tags: bots, amazon-lex, aws-sdk-net

We are creating the bots using Amazon.Lex API which is part of aws-sdk-net, this bots interacts with Amazon lex model. On executing this bot we are getting below mentioned error.

**There are other questions exists in SO with the same issue, but those are not related to aws lex sdk.**

```
    Amazon.Runtime.AmazonUnmarshallingException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Error unmarshalling response back from AWS. Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX, Response Body: <InvalidSignatureException>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

The Canonical String for this request should have been
'POST
/bot/OrderFlowers/alias/user/text

content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
host:runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
user-agent:aws-sdk-dotnet-45/3.3.1.6 aws-sdk-dotnet-core/3.3.14.1 .NET_Runtime/4.0 .NET_Framework/4.0 OS/Microsoft_Windows_NT_6.2.9200.0 ClientSync
x-amz-content-sha256:
x-amz-date:20170605T120548Z

content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date'

The String-to-Sign should have been
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20170605T120548Z
20170605/us-east-1/lex/aws4_request'
</Message>
</InvalidSignatureException>

  RequestId=
  ResponseBody=<InvalidSignatureException>
  <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

The Canonical String for this request should have been
'POST
/bot/OrderFlowers/alias/user/text

content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
host:runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
user-agent:aws-sdk-dotnet-45/3.3.1.6 aws-sdk-dotnet-core/3.3.14.1 .NET_Runtime/4.0 .NET_Framework/4.0 OS/Microsoft_Windows_NT_6.2.9200.0 ClientSync
x-amz-content-sha256:
x-amz-date:20170605T120548Z

content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date


The String-to-Sign should have been
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20170605T120548Z
20170605/us-east-1/lex/aws4_request
'
</Message>
</InvalidSignatureException>

  Source=AWSSDK.Core
  StackTrace:
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.cs:line 111
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.Handle(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ExceptionHandler.cs:line 38
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessException(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 204
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\ErrorHandler.cs:line 78
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:line 45
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Signer.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Signer.cs:line 38
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CredentialsRetriever.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CredentialsRetriever.cs:line 72
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RetryHandler\RetryHandler.cs:line 84
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:line 45
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.EndpointResolver.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\EndpointResolver.cs:line 34
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Marshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\Marshaller.cs:line 37
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\CallbackHandler.cs:line 45
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\ErrorCallbackHandler.cs:line 44
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.PipelineHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\PipelineHandler.cs:line 55
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\Handlers\MetricsHandler.cs:line 40
       at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RuntimePipeline.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\RuntimePipeline.cs:line 135
       at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.Invoke[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, IMarshaller`2 marshaller, ResponseUnmarshaller unmarshaller) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\AmazonServiceClient.cs:line 192
       at Amazon.Lex.AmazonLexClient.PostText(PostTextRequest request) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\Lex\Generated\_bcl45\AmazonLexClient.cs:line 508
       at AWSLexClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Sameer\Practice\Bots\AWSLexClient\AWSLexClient\Program.cs:line 30
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146232000
       LineNumber=0
       LinePosition=0
       Message=Root element is missing.
       Source=System.Xml
       SourceUri=""
       StackTrace:
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
            at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
            at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.XmlUnmarshallerContext.Read() in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Transform\UnmarshallerContext.cs:line 368
            at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.ErrorResponseUnmarshaller.Unmarshall(XmlUnmarshallerContext context) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Transform\ErrorResponseUnmarshaller.cs:line 36
            at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.JsonErrorResponseUnmarshaller.Unmarshall(JsonUnmarshallerContext context) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Transform\JsonErrorResponseUnmarshaller.cs:line 41
            at Amazon.Lex.Model.Internal.MarshallTransformations.PostTextResponseUnmarshaller.UnmarshallException(JsonUnmarshallerContext context, Exception innerException, HttpStatusCode statusCode) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Services\Lex\Generated\Model\Internal\MarshallTransformations\PostTextResponseUnmarshaller.cs:line 110
            at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Transform.JsonResponseUnmarshaller.UnmarshallException(UnmarshallerContext input, Exception innerException, HttpStatusCode statusCode) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Internal\Transform\ResponseUnmarshallers.cs:line 198
            at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleException(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception) in E:\JenkinsWorkspaces\v3-trebuchet-release\AWSDotNetPublic\sdk\src\Core\Amazon.Runtime\Pipeline\ErrorHandler\HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.cs:line 78
       InnerException:
```

We implemented the following code

```
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

    AmazonLexClient client = new AmazonLexClient(credentials, new AmazonLexConfig {
        ServiceURL = "https://runtime.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        DisableLogging = false,
        #region proxy setting
        ProxyCredentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxx","XXXXXX")
        #endregion
    });

    var response= client.PostText(new PostTextRequest()
    {
        BotAlias = "",
        BotName = "OrderFlowers",
        InputText = "I would like to pick up flowers",
        UserId = ""
    });

    Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", response.HttpStatusCode.ToString(), response.Message);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

**Note the version of the framework:**

> "AWSSDK.Core" version="3.3.14.1" targetFramework="net45"
>
> "AWSSDK.Lex" version="3.3.1.6" targetFramework="net45"

We took following steps before write this code

1) Create User and Group in IAM

2) Associated the following permission to group
 AmazonLexRunBotsOnly, AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess,AmazonLexReadOnly,
AmazonLexFullAccess, AmazonLexRunBotsOnly,AdministratorAccess

3) Added the user to this group.

---

We need your help to resolve this issue. Also please note we have removed access keys and other confidential data.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried adding values for "botAlias" and "user". In this example, it looks like both value are used -> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/book-trip-detail-flow.html

Comment: You are right if we set the value of BotAlias to $LATEST, program started working fine. Had to compare the http request generated from the test client that is available in the Amazon bot website with the http request generated by our program.